# Fail to start service postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I was working with postgresql, and suddenly, this stop it. I stoped service, but when i try start it, never i can do it.

```
 service postgresql start     FAIL
```

don't have a backup, and with pg_dump is imposible.

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "/mibase.backup" mydatabase
```

which is the best form to do a backup?

Comment: Your OS, the version of PostgreSQL and any error messages you got? Also: probably a better fit for dba.SE or serverfault.SE.

Comment: Check out the Postgres log files for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble with PostgreSQL 9.0.2 under Windows. The service would just stop every couple of days.  I never had trouble restarting it, though.  Never had to restart the Windows server to restart the PostgreSQL service.

With the PostgreSQL service shut down, you can [copy the database files](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html).

If you're not on the most current release of your version, you might try installing a more recent minor version. Postgresql doesn't mind running multiple versions on the same server, although they each have to listen on a different port.

The minor version number is the third digit. Above, the major version is "9.0".  If you're running 9.0.2, you want 9.0.[a number greater than 2].  Why?

"Minor releases never change the internal storage format and are always compatible with earlier and later minor releases of the same major version number, e.g., 8.4.2 is compatible with 8.4, 8.4.1 and 8.4.6." ([Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html))

So a minor version upgrade, listening on a different port, and pointing to your old data directory might let you [make a SQL dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html).  A SQL dump can be restored to any version.

A minor version upgrade pointing to a new data directory should be able to read files copied at the filesystem level. (Paragraph 2, way above.)

Comment: +1 You really squeezed the most out of an unclear question. :)

Comment: It's 10° F with wind here. I'm trying to avoid going outside.